# i/o timeout when pushing to a Git reporsitory

Tags: git, github, atlassian-sourcetree, git-lfs

I'm using the Sourcetree client for Git.

When I try to push my latest commits I get this error:

```
Pushing to https://github.com/<my project>.git
Uploading LFS objects:   0% (0/2), 1.0 GB | 23 MB/s, done
LFS: Put https://github-cloud.s3.amazonaws.com/alambic/media/236885180/82/06/8206f95c5f11de61a3cb31e8a9047de62a43c832ad3aa569ee16386b01ed53d6?actor_id=37049664: read tcp <ip>->52.216.25.116:443: i/o timeout
LFS: Put https://github-cloud.s3.amazonaws.com/alambic/media/236885180/00/99/0099579d1f280c937c1aa2a5b63d41b35df2f149d5c652f2619dadc60cbb9553?actor_id=37049664: read tcp <ip>->52.216.25.116:443: i/o timeout

error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/<my project>.git'
Completed with errors, see above.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution was to change the dialtimeout and activitytimeout lfs values, I changed them to really high values (3600).

**Edit:**

The commands I used to change the values are:

```
git config lfs.dialtimeout 3600
git config lfs.activitytimeout 3600
```

3600 being the value I used, you should obviously use a value that suits *your* needs.

Comment: Remember what you changed them from?

Comment: This seems related: https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/2636

Comment: How did you change them?  LFS just reports "WARNING: These unsafe lfsconfig keys were ignored"

Comment: @Geordie I've updated the answer to include the commands I've used

Comment: There is also `lfs.tlstimeout` and `lfs.keepalive` for additional options if it's still not working for you.